# programmatically call remove when in cellEditable/onCellEditApproved

Tags: material-table

is it possible to programmatically remove a row when editing a column value?  I have two tables where a user can update "Status" and if they update to a certain value, I'd like to remove the row and add it to the other table.

I can update the state of the other table to add the row, but when removing the row from the current table I get the error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out at least a work-around.  Resolve() the editable first then update the row in a setTimeout.  This will cause a potential timing issue if the table isnt updated for the timeout.

```
cellEditable={{
        onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
          return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            
            resolve();

            setTimeout(() => {
              //
              // REMOVE LOGIC HERE
              //
              }
            }, 50);
          });
        },
      }}
```